# Pandas 'count(distinct)' equivalent

Tags: python, pandas, count, group-by, distinct

I am using Pandas as a database substitute as I have multiple databases ([Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database), [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server), etc.), and I am unable to make a sequence of commands to a SQL equivalent.

I have a table loaded in a DataFrame with some columns:

```
YEARMONTH, CLIENTCODE, SIZE, etc., etc.
```

In SQL, to count the amount of different clients per year would be:

```sql
SELECT count(distinct CLIENTCODE) FROM table GROUP BY YEARMONTH;
```

And the result would be

```
201301    5000
201302    13245
```

How can I do that in Pandas?

Comment: if you want to compute the number of unique values for multiple columns or run an actual SQL query on a pandas dataframe, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73538957/19123103).

Answer (score 591, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
table.groupby('YEARMONTH').CLIENTCODE.nunique()
```

Example:

```
In [2]: table
Out[2]: 
   CLIENTCODE  YEARMONTH
0           1     201301
1           1     201301
2           2     201301
3           1     201302
4           2     201302
5           2     201302
6           3     201302

In [3]: table.groupby('YEARMONTH').CLIENTCODE.nunique()
Out[3]: 
YEARMONTH
201301       2
201302       3
```

Answer (score 131):

Here is another method and it is much simpler. Let’s say your dataframe name is `daat` and the column name is `YEARMONTH`:

```
daat.YEARMONTH.value_counts()
```

Comment: This does not address the question asked.

Answer (score 56):

Interestingly enough, very often `len(unique())` is a few times (3x-15x) faster than `nunique()`.

Answer (score 20):

I am also using `nunique` but it will be very helpful if you have to use an aggregate function like `'min', 'max', 'count' or 'mean'` etc.

```
df.groupby('YEARMONTH')['CLIENTCODE'].transform('nunique') #count(distinct)
df.groupby('YEARMONTH')['CLIENTCODE'].transform('min')     #min
df.groupby('YEARMONTH')['CLIENTCODE'].transform('max')     #max
df.groupby('YEARMONTH')['CLIENTCODE'].transform('mean')    #average
df.groupby('YEARMONTH')['CLIENTCODE'].transform('count')   #count
```

Answer (score 18):

## Distinct of column along with aggregations on other columns

To get the distinct number of values for any column (`CLIENTCODE` in your case), we can use `nunique`. We can pass the input as a dictionary in `agg` function, along with aggregations on other columns:

```py
grp_df = df.groupby('YEARMONTH').agg({'CLIENTCODE': ['nunique'],
                                      'other_col_1': ['sum', 'count']})

# to flatten the multi-level columns
grp_df.columns = ["_".join(col).strip() for col in grp_df.columns.values]

# if you wish to reset the index
grp_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `crosstab`, this will return more information than `groupby` `nunique`:

```
pd.crosstab(df.YEARMONTH,df.CLIENTCODE)
Out[196]:
CLIENTCODE  1  2  3
YEARMONTH
201301      2  1  0
201302      1  2  1
```

After a little bit of modification, it yields the result:

```
pd.crosstab(df.YEARMONTH,df.CLIENTCODE).ne(0).sum(1)
Out[197]:
YEARMONTH
201301    2
201302    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach to have count distinct over multiple columns. Let's have some data:

```
data = {'CLIENT_CODE':[1,1,2,1,2,2,3],
        'YEAR_MONTH':[201301,201301,201301,201302,201302,201302,201302],
        'PRODUCT_CODE': [100,150,220,400,50,80,100]
       }
table = pd.DataFrame(data)
table

CLIENT_CODE YEAR_MONTH  PRODUCT_CODE
0   1       201301      100
1   1       201301      150
2   2       201301      220
3   1       201302      400
4   2       201302      50
5   2       201302      80
6   3       201302      100
```

Now, list the columns of interest and use groupby in a slightly modified syntax:

```
columns = ['YEAR_MONTH', 'PRODUCT_CODE']
table[columns].groupby(table['CLIENT_CODE']).nunique()
```

We obtain:

```
YEAR_MONTH  PRODUCT_CODE CLIENT_CODE
1           2            3
2           2            3
3           1            1
```

Answer (score 1):

With the new Pandas version, it is easy to get as a data frame:

```
unique_count = pd.groupby(['YEARMONTH'], as_index=False).agg(uniq_CLIENTCODE=('CLIENTCODE', pd.Series.count))
```

Comment: What is the version number? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58204139/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

Now you are also able to use [dplyr](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html?highlight=dplyr#assigning-new-columns-in-method-chains) syntax in Python to do it:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tibble, group_by, summarise, n_distinct
>>>
>>> data = tibble(
...     CLIENT_CODE=[1,1,2,1,2,2,3],
...     YEAR_MONTH=[201301,201301,201301,201302,201302,201302,201302]
... )
>>>
>>> data >> group_by(f.YEAR_MONTH) >> summarise(n=n_distinct(f.CLIENT_CODE))
   YEAR_MONTH       n
      <int64> <int64>
0      201301       2
1      201302       3
```

Comment: What is "dplyr syntax"? Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68012034/edit) an (authoritative) reference to it (for context)? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 1):

Create a pivot table and use the *nunique* series function:

```
ID = [ 123, 123, 123, 456, 456, 456, 456, 789, 789]
domain = ['vk.com', 'vk.com', 'twitter.com', 'vk.com', 'facebook.com',
          'vk.com', 'google.com', 'twitter.com', 'vk.com']
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':ID, 'domain':domain})
fp = pd.pivot_table(data=df, index='domain', aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique)
print(fp)
```

Output:

```
               id
domain
facebook.com   1
google.com     1
twitter.com    2
vk.com         3
```

Comment: But the sample data does not match the question (YEARMONTH, CLIENTCODE, and SIZE). [The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411158/pandas-countdistinct-equivalent/15411596#15411596) and most of the other answers do. This answer (in its current state) would be a better match for question *[Count unique values with Pandas per groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309729/)*.

Comment: pivot table does the aggregation using a function.

Answer (score 0):

- To obtain the number of different clients and sizes per year (i.e. number of unique values of **multiple columns**), use a list of columns:

  ```py
  df.groupby('YEARMONTH')[['CLIENTCODE', 'SIZE']].nunique()
  ```
- Actually, the result from the above code can be obtained using SQL syntax on `df` using `pandasql` (a module built on pandas that lets you query pandas DataFrames using SQL syntax).

  ```py
  #! pip install pandasql
  from pandasql import sqldf
  sqldf("""
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CLIENTCODE), 
         COUNT(DISTINCT SIZE)
    FROM df 
    GROUP BY YEARMONTH
  """)
  ```
- If you want to keep YEARMONTH as a column, i.e. the analog of the following SQL query

  ```sql
  SELECT YEARMONTH, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT CLIENTCODE),
         COUNT(DISTINCT SIZE)
    FROM df 
    GROUP BY YEARMONTH
  ```

  in pandas is the following (set `as_index` to `False`):

  ```py
  df.groupby('YEARMONTH', as_index=False)[['CLIENTCODE', 'SIZE']].nunique()
  ```
- If you need to set custom names to the aggregated columns, i.e. the analog of the following SQL query:

  ```sql
  SELECT YEARMONTH, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT CLIENTCODE) AS `No. clients`, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT SIZE) AS `No. size`
    FROM df 
    GROUP BY YEARMONTH
  ```

  use named aggregation in pandas:

  ```py
  (
      df.groupby('YEARMONTH', as_index=False)
        .agg(**{'No. clients':('CLIENTCODE', 'nunique'), 
                'No. size':('SIZE', 'nunique')})
  )
  ```