# Count unique values per groups with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, unique

I need to count unique `ID` values in every `domain`.

I have data:

```
 ID, domain
123, vk.com
123, vk.com
123, twitter.com
456, vk.com'
456, facebook.com
456, vk.com
456, google.com
789, twitter.com
789, vk.com
```

I try `df.groupby(['domain', 'ID']).count()`

But I want to get

```
domain       count
vk.com        3
twitter.com   2
facebook.com  1
google.com    1
```

Answer (score 427, accepted):

You need [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
df = df.groupby('domain')['ID'].nunique()

print (df)
domain
'facebook.com'    1
'google.com'      1
'twitter.com'     2
'vk.com'          3
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

If you need to [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) `'` characters:

```
df = df.ID.groupby([df.domain.str.strip("'")]).nunique()
print (df)
domain
facebook.com    1
google.com      1
twitter.com     2
vk.com          3
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

Or as [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309729/count-unique-values-with-pandas#comment64036411_38309823) commented:

```
df.groupby(df.domain.str.strip("'"))['ID'].nunique()
```

You can retain the column name like this:

```
df = df.groupby(by='domain', as_index=False).agg({'ID': pd.Series.nunique})
print(df)
    domain  ID
0       fb   1
1      ggl   1
2  twitter   2
3       vk   3
```

The difference is that `nunique()` returns a Series and `agg()` returns a DataFrame.

Answer (score 355):

Generally to count distinct values in single column, you can use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df.domain.value_counts()

#'vk.com'          5
#'twitter.com'     2
#'facebook.com'    1
#'google.com'      1
#Name: domain, dtype: int64
```

To see how many unique values in a column, use [`Series.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html):

```
df.domain.nunique()
# 4
```

To get all these distinct values, you can use [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) or [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), the slight difference between the two functions is that `unique` return a `numpy.array` while `drop_duplicates` returns a `pandas.Series`:

```
df.domain.unique()
# array(["'vk.com'", "'twitter.com'", "'facebook.com'", "'google.com'"], dtype=object)

df.domain.drop_duplicates()
#0          'vk.com'
#2     'twitter.com'
#4    'facebook.com'
#6      'google.com'
#Name: domain, dtype: object
```

---

As for this specific problem, since you'd like to count distinct value with respect to another variable, besides `groupby` method provided by other answers here, you can also simply drop duplicates firstly and then do `value_counts()`:

```
import pandas as pd
df.drop_duplicates().domain.value_counts()

# 'vk.com'          3
# 'twitter.com'     2
# 'facebook.com'    1
# 'google.com'      1
# Name: domain, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 71):

df.domain.value_counts()

```
>>> df.domain.value_counts()

vk.com          5

twitter.com     2

google.com      1

facebook.com    1

Name: domain, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 18):

If I understand correctly, you want the number of different `ID`s for every `domain`. Then you can try this:

```
output = df.drop_duplicates()
output.groupby('domain').size()
```

Output:

```
    domain
facebook.com    1
google.com      1
twitter.com     2
vk.com          3
dtype: int64
```

You could also use `value_counts`, which is slightly less efficient. But the best is [Jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309729/count-unique-values-with-pandas-per-groups/38309823#38309823) using `nunique`:

```
%timeit df.drop_duplicates().groupby('domain').size()
1000 loops, best of 3: 939 µs per loop
%timeit df.drop_duplicates().domain.value_counts()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.1 ms per loop
%timeit df.groupby('domain')['ID'].nunique()
1000 loops, best of 3: 440 µs per loop
```