# Counting Unique Values of Categories of Column Given Condition on other Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame where the rows represent a transaction done by a certain user. Note that more than one row can have the same user_id. Given the column names **gender** and **user_id** running:

```
df.gender.value_counts()
```

returns the frequencies but they are spurious since they may be possibly counting a given user more than once. So for example, it may tell me there are 50 male individuals while they are actually much less.

Is there a way I can condition `value_counts()` to count only once per user_id?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count unique values with pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309729/count-unique-values-with-pandas)

Comment: I wonder why you don't select unique `user_id` and group by `gender` afterwards. Hopefully, your users don't change their gender too often..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use panda's `groupby` on your dataframe:

```
users = {'A': 'male', 'B': 'female', 'C': 'female'}
ul = [{'id': k, 'gender': users[k]} for _ in range(50) for k in random.choice(users.keys())]
df = pd.DataFrame(ul)

print(df.groupby('gender')['id'].nunique())
```

This yields (depending on fortune's random choice, but chances are *"quite high"* that each of three keys is chosen at least once for 50 samples):

```
gender
female    2
male      1
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the first post but just to make the groupby simpler:

```
df.groupby('user_id').first().count() will give you counts of each variable
```

or alternatively:

```
pd.value_counts(df.groupby('user_id').first().reset_index().gender)
```