# How to find distinct count of data frame particular column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df:

```
Field1 Field2
1      2
3      4
5      6
1      7
3      8
```

Please let me know how to find distinct count of df['Field1'], Results should be 3
In SQL we use query like this.

```
select count(distinct Field1) as Field1DistCount from df
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count unique values with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309729/count-unique-values-with-pandas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html#pandas-series-nunique):

```
df['Field1'].nunique()
```

Output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
print(df['COLUMN_NAME_HERE'].nunique())
```

If you want a dataframe of the unique values you could do ([and here is a good link to go along with it](https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_list_unique_values_in_column.html)):

```
print(df['COLUMN_NAME_HERE'].unique())
```

And if you want the counts of those unique values [using `value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
print(df['COLUMN_NAME_HERE'].value_counts())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even use value_counts() to get the count of unique values for a particular value present in a column.

Example :

```
df['col_name'].value_counts().values #This will fetch you the count
```

And if you want to store the unique values in another column then you can execute the below command :

```
df['col_name'].value_counts().index
```

Let me know if this helps. Thanks