# How to show columns that have different values in rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas DataFrame with 2 rows:

```
+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
|       ID|     Type|      Index|        Code|
+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
|111111111|       aa|          1|         XXX|
|111111111|       aa|       null|         XXX|
```

How can I show those columns that have different values between rows of `df`? (there might be more than 2 rows).

In the above-shown example, the expected output is `Index`, because the first row has `Index` equal to 1 and the second row has `Index` equal to null.

Comment: Are you looking for `nunique`? `df.columns[df.nunique(axis=0, dropna=False).gt(1)]  `

Comment: Are you trying to compare values across every row? Or consecutive rows only? Are you claiming that every row should have the same column values (with exceptions)?

Comment: @cs95: Across all existing rows in `df`.

Comment: So, can you confirm that `df.columns[df.nunique(axis=0, dropna=False).gt(1)]` is what you want? Or maybe you want to do this per ID as rafaelc mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply select the column/s (or the dataframe) with columns having unique values more than 1. You can get those columns whose values are distinct with

```
def cols_having_unique(df):
    my_cols = []
    for col in df.columns:
        if df[col].nunique(dropna=False) > 1:
            my_cols.append(col)
    return df[my_cols].copy()

new_df = cols_having_unique(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
for col in df.columns:
   if len(df[col].value_counts()) > 1:
      print('The column ' +  col + ' has different values')
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through `pandas.DataFrame.columns` and check if two rows have the same value for every column.

```
import pandas as pd
data=[
    [111111111,'aa',1,'XXX'],
    [111111111,'aa','null','XXX'],
    [111111111,'aa','null','YYY']
]
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["ID", "Type", "Index", "Code"])

def get_different_columns(r1, r2):
    different_col_list=[]
    for column in df.columns:
        if df.iloc[r1][column] != df.iloc[r2][column]:
            different_col_list.append(column)
    return different_col_list

print(get_different_columns(0,1))
#['Index']

print(get_different_columns(1,2))
#['Code']

print(get_different_columns(0,2))
#['Index', 'Code']
```

Answer (score -3):

I suppose you can count distinct values in a single column by iterating through all the columns.

**How to count distinct values**: [Count unique values with pandas per groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309729/count-unique-values-with-pandas-per-groups/38309823)

Comment: If this is a duplicate, please vote to close as duplicate or leave a comment.  **Do not** make an answer that just links to the duplicate.