# Unique count changes using groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count, unique

**Required task**

I have the following `DataFrame` and I want to get the data to simply have the unique count changes of the `Rating` for each `id`

```
             date  Rating  id
0      2019-12-31    A      1
1      2019-12-31    B      2
2      2019-11-30    A      1
3      2019-11-30    A      2
4      2019-10-31    B      1
5      2019-10-31    A      2
6      2019-09-30    C      1
7      2019-09-30    A      2
8      2019-08-31    B      1
9      2019-08-31    B      2
```

**Goal**

```
id   Rating   Unique Count
1      A        1
1      B        2
1      C        1
2      A        1
2      B        2
```

The above `DataFrame` is simply an example, I am not exactly sure how it would look it pandas. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309729/count-unique-values-with-pandas-per-groups

Comment: It seems dupe, if not, can you explain more? e.g first 2 rows of output, also last row `2      A        1` and 4th row `2      A        1` are same?

Comment: The link above does not achieve the desired output. For example, for id 1, Rating starts at A, then goes to B, then C, then back to B. The link would only count B once. I am interested in it increasing the count for the rating if it changes. E.g. B would be 2, not 1