# How to calculate the count of how many names are there in the column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the count of how many names there are included in the the column of dataframe in Python.

I get the column names from dataframe as defined command

```
df["Names_Column"]
```

Here is the values of one column in dataframe

```
Names_Column
Damandeep Singh Baggan, Smita Malhotra, Baba Sehgal, Deepak Chachra
Damandeep Singh Baggan, Smita Malhotra, Deepak Chachra
...
```

I want to get a result of a count like this.

```
Name                     Count
Damandeep Singh Baggan     4
Deepak Chachra             3
Smita Malhotra             2
...
```

I can try to this code to seperate names but I couldn't do it.

```
separate = df["Names_Column"].str.split(",")
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Providing  a [mre] would be a good start, reading [ask] helps as well.

Comment: Hi Tony, the function that you are looking for is value_counts();

but I'm afraid that this question. is duplicated.

you can find the answer in the following posts:
1) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411158/pandas-countdistinct-equivalent)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411158/pandas-countdistinct-equivalent]
2) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309729/count-unique-values-with-pandas-per-groups)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309729/count-unique-values-with-pandas-per-groups]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining `explode`, and `value_counts` on the column solves this problem.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
['Damandeep Singh Baggan, Smita Malhotra, Baba Sehgal, Deepak Chachra'],
['Damandeep Singh Baggan, Smita Malhotra, Deepak Chachra']],columns=['Names_Column'])
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(', ').explode())
df2['Names_Column'].value_counts()
```

returns

```
                        count
Names_Column                 
Baba Sehgal                 1
Damandeep Singh Baggan      2
Deepak Chachra              2
Smita Malhotra              2
```