# Get count of each unique values groupby another column and transform them into columns

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like below:

| id | name | colA | colB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Ana | abc | xyz |
| One | Ana | abc | xyz |
| One | Ana | bde | xyz |
| One | Ana | bde | xyz |
| One | Ana | bde | yhn |
| One | Ana | bde | yhn |
| One | Ana | bde | qwe |
| One | Ana | teh | qwe |
| Two | Bob | abc | qwe |
| Two | Bob | teh | qwe |
| Two | Bob | pop | omg |

I need to transform my dataframe as

| id | name | abc | bde | teh | pop | xyz | yhn | qwe | omg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Ana | 2 | 5 | 1 | 0 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| Two | Bob | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 |

I wrote below code to achieve this but it do not gives me expected output and also I have no idea how to perform it for multiple columns. Please help.

`df = df.groupby(['id','colA']).size().reset_index(name='colA_counts')`

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309729/count-unique-values-per-groups-with-pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this:

```
a = df[["id", "name", "A"]].copy()
b = df[["id", "name", "B"]].copy()
b.columns = ["id", "name", "A"]

       
result = pd.concat([a, b]).value_counts().reset_index()
result.columns = ["id", "name", "A", "count"]
pd.pivot_table(result, index=["id", "name"], columns=["A"], values="count").fillna(0)
```

What I'm basically doing is, I first create a new DataFrame, concatenated of the original one where both A and B are just called "A" then as you don't make any difference of whether it is A or B. In this I let it count the different values, i.e. combinations of id, name and value.

Then I pivot the table so, that the values in "A" are considered the columns, finally I fill up all those combinations that don't appear in the data with zeros by calling `fillna(0)`.

What I btw don't understand is, where the 1 in the "one ana pop" in your example comes from. Your data is not providing this.

Comment: I have updated the data for "one ana pop".

Comment: Alright - thank you. But did my answer help you? Or are there problems still?

Comment: yes, and thank you so much @Christian

Comment: I know I had not added it to my original question but if you could answer, I will be grateful. If I have another categorical column for which I need to take MODE and get data like this, how could I do so? @Christian