# Pandas: What is the fastest way to search a large dataframe

Tags: pandas

pandas newbie question:

I have a dataframe with millions of rows, a sample output would be:

```
c_id  c1   c2
0     10  100
0     15  110
0     15  112
2     96  120
56    43  42
```

for each customer_id, i want to create a table do some stuff to it. What's the best way to do it?
I sorted the dataframe by c_id, then set the index to it:

```
df = df.sort('c_id', ascending=False)
df = df.set_index('c_id')
```

but a simple operation like:

```
temp_df = df.loc[:0]
```

takes forever, what's the fastest way to approach this problem? 
I thought a sorted set_index would do the trick. I guess not.

**EDIT1:**

I want to get the list of all the unique values of c1, for each value of c_id. so something like:

```
df.loc[:0].c1.unique()
```

Comment: there might be quite a few different approaches depending on "stuff you want to do with subsets of your DF". Try to explain what are you trying to achieve and post your desired data set...

Comment: it's non-performant to have a non-unique index, you'd better off just `group`ing on the `c_id`, you can then just do `gp.get_group(your_c_id)` to return you a specific group but you'd need to do some aggregation on the `groupby` object in order to return a series/df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't explicitly create groups, but use pandas [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

For example, say that you want to find the average value for client, you can do:

```
df.groupby(by = df['c_id']).mean()
```

and so on.

You can also apply (almost) arbitrary transformations, using `.apply` and `.transform` methods (although in-built methods like mean, std, min, max is much more efficient, as they are optimised).

To answer your specific question, you can do:

```
df.groupby('c_id').c1.nunique()
```

which gives:

```
c_id
0     2
20    1
56    1
Name: c1, dtype: int64
```

Notice that some questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411158/pandas-countdistinct-equivalent) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411158/pandas-countdistinct-equivalent)) suggest that .nunique is not the faster way to go and this is the alternative way to go:

```
df.groupby('c_id').c1.apply(lambda x: len(x.unique()))
```

(I haven't done any benchmarking myself...)

Comment: pretty much the right answer. What I was looking for was :
df.groupby('c_id').c1.unique()

Did not know pandas can hold an array.