# group by two columns count in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2017-1-1', '2017-1-1', '2017-1-2', '2017-1-2', '2017-1-3'],
    'Groups': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two']})

    Date      Groups  
0  2017-1-1    one       
1  2017-1-1    one       
2  2017-1-2    one       
3  2017-1-2    two       
4  2017-1-3    two
```

How can I generate a new DataFrame like this?

```
     Date    Groups_counts     
0  2017-1-1    1        
1  2017-1-2    2        
2  2017-1-3    1
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you mean grouping by how many unique values there are in the second column? I'm guessing you are, but you should explain that in your question. Also, what did you try? What output did you get? See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411158/pandas-countdistinct-equivalent

Answer (score 2):

To get count of unique records use:

```
df.groupby('Date')['Groups'].nunique()
```

Comment: Thanks. What i should add if i want to sort values based on Groups_counts's values?

Comment: @ahbon just `sort_values()` using `df.groupby('Date')['Groups'].nunique().sort_values(ascending=False)`.

Comment: Wonderful answer :)