# How to aggregate groupBy by another column's value pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this.

```
         order_id  product_id  add_to_cart_order  reordered  user_id eval_set  order_number  order_dow  order_hour_of_day  days_since_prior_order
0               1       49302                  1          1   112108    train             4          4                 10                     9.0
1               1       11109                  2          1   112108    train             4          4                 10                     9.0
2               1       10246                  3          0   112108    train             4          4                 10                     9.0
3               1       49683                  4          0   112108    train             4          4                 10                     9.0
4               1       43633                  5          1   112108    train             4          4                 10                     9.0
5               1       13176                  6          0   112108    train             4          4                 10                     9.0
6               1       47209                  7          0   112108    train             4          4                 10                     9.0
7               1       22035                  8          1   112108    train             4          4                 10                     9.0
8              36       39612                  1          0    79431    train            23          6                 18                    30.0
9              36       19660                  2          1    79431    train            23          6                 18                    30.0
10             36       49235                  3          0    79431    train            23          6                 18                    30.0
11             36       43086                  4          1    79431    train            23          6                 18                    30.0
12             36       46620                  5          1    79431    train            23          6                 18                    30.0
13             36       34497                  6          1    79431    train            23          6                 18                    30.0
14             36       48679                  7          1    79431    train            23          6                 18                    30.0
15             36       46979                  8          1    79431    train            23          6                 18                    30.0
16             38       11913                  1          0    42756    train             6          6                 16                    24.0
17             38       18159                  2          0    42756    train             6          6                 16                    24.0
```

So all rows tagged order_id == 1, all are corresponding to 1 order. I would like to figure out how many unique orders a user has made. The outcome should look like:

```
user_id   unique_orders
 112108               1
  79431               1
  42756               1
```

It's obvious that I should groupBy `order_id`. But what is the agg here? Do I need to do two groupBys? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `df.groupby('user_id').order_id.nuniques()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as suggested @Quang Hoang 
in the comment, this question is of direct application of [GroupBy.nunique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html), 
I add what is necessary to obtain a `dataframe` like the one shown in your expected output:

```
df_nunique=df.groupby('user_id')['order_id'].nunique().rename('unique_orders').reset_index()
print(df_nunique)
```

---

```
   user_id  unique_orders
0    42756              1
1    79431              1
2   112108              1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following code. It seems that `len(unique())` performs better than `nunique()`

```
print(df.groupby('user_id')['order_id'].apply(lambda x: len(x.unique())))
```

Comment: You didn't close single quotes in column ref, before ```apply```

Comment: Edited, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Why does nunique not work?

Comment: I got the expected output

Comment: I never stated it doesn't work. I stated that it performs better. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411158/pandas-countdistinct-equivalent