# Pandas - find which id has more than one corresponding value in another column

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe `df`, where I need to find if some `player_id` has changed its `team` value along the season:

```
player_id      team
1         Liverpool
2        Manchester
1         Liverpool
2        Manchester
1         Liverpool
2         Tottenham
```

To find duplicated pairs I would simply:

```
duplicate = df[df.duplicated(['player_id', 'team'])]
```

But the dataframe has duplicated pairs as a rule.

I need to find all cases when one player_id has more than one team, and print:

```
2
```

How so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas count(distinct) equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411158/pandas-countdistinct-equivalent)

Comment: not really. I don't need all ocurrences, but to pinpoint wich id has two teams

Comment: Would this help? `list(set(df[df.groupby('id')['team'].transform('nunique').ne(1)]['id'].tolist()))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[df.groupby('player_id')['team'].transform('nunique').ne(1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` and calculate the number of unique values per group with the method `nunique()`:

```
df.groupby('player_id')['team'].nunique().loc[lambda x: x > 1].index
```