# How to get unique values counts of a column for other boolean columns?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I have a dataframe containing a set of columns all of which are booleans. I would like to get a unique count of another column (an ID column) for each of these columns (and respective boolean values)

ex:

```
data = [
    ["ABC", True, False],
    ["DEF", False, False],
    ["GHI", False, True],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["ID", "CONTAINS_Y", "CONTAINS_X"])

df.groupby("CONTAINS_Y")["ID"].nunique().reset_index()
```

yields:

```
  CONTAINS_Y    ID
    False       2
    True        1
```

I would like a command that yields:

```
  CONTAINS_Y    ID
    False       2
    True        1
  CONTAINS_X    ID
    False       2
    True        1
```

Is there a way to group all boolean columns to get unique counts? Or does it have to be done individually?

There are other similar questions ([Pandas count(distinct) equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411158/pandas-countdistinct-equivalent)) but the solutions haven't worked for what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `melt` then `groupby`

```
df.melt(id_vars='ID').groupby(['variable', 'value']).nunique()

#                  ID
#variable   value    
#CONTAINS_X False   2
#           True    1
#CONTAINS_Y False   2
#           True    1
```

---

`melt` reshapes your DataFrame from a wide to a long format so that it will work with a single `groupby`

```
df.melt(id_vars='ID')
#    ID    variable  value
#0  ABC  CONTAINS_Y   True
#1  DEF  CONTAINS_Y  False
#2  GHI  CONTAINS_Y  False
#3  ABC  CONTAINS_X  False
#4  DEF  CONTAINS_X  False
#5  GHI  CONTAINS_X   True
```